# Yup conditional validation - when

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm try to conditionally validate nested object based on the parent value with `when` method but I didn't manage to make it work.

```
const firstStep = Yup.object().shape({
  accountHolder: Yup.object().shape({
    accountType: Yup.number()
      .typeError("Required")
      .required("Required"),
    mailingAddress: Yup.object().shape({
      address1: Yup.string().when("accountType", {
        is: 2,
        then: Yup.string()
          .min(5, "Min 5 char")
          .required("Required")
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: From what I've understood inside their documentation `when` is only applicable to a sibling attribute or sibling children. The `acountType` is not a sibling but a parent, that might explain why it does not work. https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema

Comment: Yeah,  do you have a suggestion how to make it works?

Comment: The easy solution is to avoid the nested structure then you'll be able to use `when` function. Otherwise you take a look at this GitHub issue that might help https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/225

Answer (score 3):

The below will work:

```
const firstStep = Yup.object().shape({
        accountHolder: Yup.object().shape({
            accountType: Yup.number()
                .typeError("Required")
                .required("Required"),
            mailingAddress: Yup.object().when("accountType", {
                is: 2,
                then: Yup.object().shape({
                    address1: Yup.string()
                        .min(5, "Min 5 char")
                        .required("Required")
                })
            })
        })
    });
```